# Why do I have to stop/restart cups in redhat linux in order to use a custom filter?

Tags: linux, rhel, ruby, cups

A colleague wrote a filter utility for me in ruby that allows me to print barcodes from a textfile. (The filter replaces @{blah} with the proper PCL and a barcode checksum character so that "blah" prints in a barcode font.)

I call this filter from an executable in my local bin directory. However on a fresh reboot, this process fails. (I can switch between 2 particular failures by manipulating permissions; either the filter fails to replace @{blah} with anything, or nothing prints.)

If I stop and restart cups, it all works like I want it to. How can I make this work without having to restart CUPS?

Comment: We'd need to see the code of the filter and an exact description of how it's installed.

Comment: The user did not respond on serverfault.com - how probably will he respond here, where he has no account?

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing: Maybe cups gets started, before your home is mounted?

Maybe, if you restart cups on rc.local as latest process, or even after login with a sudo-command?